# Not able to run system command through perl script

Tags: regex, perl, cgi

Hi i am inserting image location into particular line of file using Perl one-liner code as below

```
 my $image="/home/users/images/image1.tar";
 system(q(perl -pi -e 'print "\n$image" if ($. == 5 && $_=~ /^\s*$/ )' myfile.txt));
```

i am not able to insert a image location into the file .
please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why are you using `system`?

Comment: if i use backticks i am getting error so using system. and i don't want to store the results in any variable

Comment: Using `system` in Perl to call Perl? There should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out, using single quotes `q{}` did not allow your `$image` variable to interpolate.

To fix, just concatenate that variable into your string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $image = '/home/users/images/image1.tar';
system(q{perl -pi -e 'print "\n} . $image . q{" if ($. == 5 && $_=~ /^\s*$/ )' myfile.txt});
```

However, a much better solution is just to do this processing local to your perl script.

The following does the exact same processing without the secondary call to perl by using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
my $image = "/home/users/images/image1.tar";

local @ARGV = 'myfile.txt';
local $^I = '';
while (<>) {
    print "\n$image" if $. == 5 && $_ =~ /^\s*$/;
    print;
}
```

For additional methods for editing a file, just read [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're shelling out to a second Perl process to do this. Why not just do the processing within the original Perl program?

But your problem seems to be that the string you're passing to system is in single quotes (using `q(...)`) which means that the `$image` variable won't be expanded. You probably want to change that to a double-quoted string (using `qq(...)`).

**Update:**

This is why shelling out to an external process is fraught with difficulty. You have one variable (`$image`) which needs to be passed though and another variable (`$_`) which needs to be internal to the second process. You also have an escape sequence (`\s`) which the shell is trying (but failing) to interpret.

Liberal application of backslashes to escape special characters gives this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $image='/home/users/images/image1.tar';
system(qq(perl -pi -e 'print "\n$image" if (\$. == 5 && /^\\s*\$/ )' myfile.txt));
```

Which seems to work. But I still think you'd be far better off doing this all in one Perl program.

Comment: the same way i want to remove line i tried in this way system(qq(perl -ni -e 'print unless /$image/' myfile.txt)); not deleting can you please help me

Comment: Turning on `use strict` and `use warnings` will make the problem pretty obvious.